# Group results together at top of column without blanks

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, office365, formula

**Problem:** I have a made up formation as shown in the attached image. As you can see because I have impurities I have blank cells in columns A and Columns C. Although column B is not relevant for the final result it causes the results to be spaced out.

[image]

All I wish to be able to do is make column C have the desired output of column D. i.e. minus the blank cells, however really don't know how to achieve this.

The actual formula I wish to apply this to in Column C is `=IF(K3="-",J3,((K3/100)*(L3/100)*100))`.

Alternatively I could Use C As the output and group these together in Column D via some formula but again I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=(FILTER(A2:A18,A2:A18<>"")/330)*100
```

Comment: @iNick1, a little less verbose could even be: `=FILTER(A2:A18,A2:A18<>"")/3.3`